# Rails - Custom Validation For Having A Single Value Once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

so I have these two models:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :event_tags
attr_accessible :tag_id, :tag_type, :value
end

class EventTag < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tag
attr_accessible :tag_id, :event_id, :region
end
```

and this table for Tags:

```
**tag_id**    **tag_type**      **value**
    1         "funLevel"        "Boring..."
    2         "funLevel"        "A Little"
    3         "funLevel"        "Hellz ya"

    4         "generic"         "Needs less clowns"
    5         "generic"         "Lazer Tag"
    ...
```

What I would like to do is write a custom validation where it checks to see:

- Each event_id has **only one** tag_type of "funLevel" attached to it, but can have more than one "generic" tags

For example:

```
t1 = EventTag.new(:tag_id => 1, :event_id =>777, :region => 'US')
t1.save  # success

t2 = EventTag.new(:tag_id => 2, :event_id =>777, :region => 'US')
t2.save  # failure 
         # because (event_id: 777) already has a tag_type of 
         # "funLevel" associated with it

t3 = EventTag.new(:tag_id => 4, :event_id =>777, :region => 'US')
t3.save  # success, because as (tag_id:4) is not "funLevel" type
```

I have come up with one ugly solution:

```
def cannot_have_multiple_funLevel_tag
  list_of_tag_ids = EventTag.where("event_id = ?", event_id).pluck(:tag_id)
  if(Tag.where("tag_id in ?", list_of_tag_ids).pluck(:tag_type).include? "funLevel")
    errors.add(:tag_id, "Already has a Fun Level Tag!")
end
```

Being new to rails, is there a more better/more elegant/more inexpensive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your data structured means that the inbuilt Rails validations are probably not going to be a heap of help to you. **If** the `funLevel` attribute was directly accessible by the `EventTag` class, you could just use something like:

```
# event_tag.rb
validate :tag_type, uniqueness: { scope: :event_id },
    if: Proc.new { |tag| tag.tag_type == "funLevel" }
```

(unfortunately, from a quick test you don't seem to be able to validate the uniqueness of a virtual attribute.)

Without that, you're probably stuck using a custom validation. The obvious improvement to the custom validation you have (given it looks like you want to have the validation on `EventTag`) would be to not run the validation unless that `EventTag` is a `funLevel` tag:

```
def cannot_have_multiple_funLevel_tag
  return unless self.tag.tag_type == "funLevel"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah, due to not having full control over the database, im kind of forced to work with what i have. I do like the alternative of your custom validator, didnt think I could use the tag model as an attribute.

Comment: Yeah, associations add a bunch of methods which make accessing and interacting with the associated models pretty easy. If you're in a reading mood, check out the [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) Rails guide, and in particular the [detailed association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference).